# Set initial value and then make next value as the initial one

Tags: javascript, loops, indexing, ecmascript-6

I have values coming from an array as a string from one function to another

```js
const func1 = () => {
  let myArray = ["Harry", "Hermione", "Ron", "Ginny", "Luna"];
  myArray.map((arr, i) => func2(arr, i));
}

const func2 = (arrString, index) => {
  let before, after;
  if (index === 0) {
    before = arrString;
    after = null;
  }
}

func1();
```

After the first iteration(`index===0`) I want `after = before` value a when and `before = arrString(index=1)`. I am not sure how to loop that.

Expected results:

```
before = "Harry", after = null
before = "Hermione", after = "Harry"
before = "Ron", after = "Hermione"
before = "Ginny", after = "Ron"
before = "Luna", after = "Ginny"
before = null, after = "Luna"
```

Comment: You need to make `after` and `before` global variables so the values persist between calls.

Comment: BTW, if you're not using the returned values of the callback function, you should use `forEach()`, not `map()`.

Comment: @Barmar, why global since I am only using them inside the function?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand what you want, but I thought you wanted to remember the `before` and `after` from a previous iteration.

Comment: @Barmar I did. But I still don't understand why it needs to be global

Comment: Your code doesn't actually do anything. It just assigns local variables that are never used. Please show what the expected result should be.

Comment: If it's not global, the variable goes away when the function returns.

Comment: You could also use a closure that captures those variables, or a class instance.

Comment: @Barmar, I added the expected result

Comment: @Barmar, sorry made a mistake. Updated by expected result

Comment: There are only 5 array elements. How do you expect to get 6 results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map()` and `forEach()` also pass the array being iterated over as a third argument to the callback function. You can use this to access other indexes of the array.

```js
const func1 = () => {
  let myArray = ["Harry", "Hermione", "Ron", "Ginny", "Luna"];
  myArray.forEach((elt, i, arr) => func2(elt, i, arr));
}

const func2 = (arrString, index, array) => {
  let before = arrString, after;
  if (index === 0) {
    after = null;
  } else {
    after = array[index - 1];
  }
  console.log(`before = ${before} after = ${after}`);
}

func1();
```